# Sql Declaring a variable in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

i have created a stored procedure and in which i want to set a rowid and table name from select query to a variable but when iam executing my code in sql the bunch of errors are appears

i have decalre a variable but its keep saying to decalare table

heres My code which i have written

```
USE [DB_A4BA76_logistic]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE RecoverLogs @id int
AS
declare @TableName nvarchar(50)
declare @RowId int
set @TableName= ( select Logs.tableName from logs where Logs.id=@id)
set @Rowid= ( select Logs.Rowid from logs where id=@id)
Update @TableName set UpdateStatus='0' where id = @Rowid
if(select UpdateStatus from @TableName where id = @Rowid) = '0'
select 1
else
select 2
GO;
```

and these error are appearing after executing the above code

```
Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure RecoverLogs, Line 7
Must declare the table variable "@TableName".
Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure RecoverLogs, Line 8
Must declare the table variable "@TableName".
```

Comment: You can't use a variable/expression to replace the value of an object; it must be a literal. You'll have to use dynamic SQL here.

Comment: Why don't you use select into ?

Comment: How do you `SELECT....INTO` with a dynamic object, @AmiraBedhiafi?

Comment: i used Select .... into but still error appears

SELECT Logs.tableName INTO @TableName FROM logs WHERE Logs.id=50

following errors Appears

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '@TableName'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 2
Must declare the scalar variable "@TableName".

Comment: @MoiezHussain I thought you're storing data in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a stab in the dark, and makes some assumptions, but I suspect this is what you want. Note I changed the `SELECT` to an `OUTPUT` parameter, as that seemed like a better fit here as well.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.RecoverLogs @id int, @status tinyint OUTPUT
AS BEGIN



    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

    SELECT @SQL = N'DECLARE @RI table (UpdateStatus int);' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                  N'UPDATE dbo.' + QUOTENAME(tableName) + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                  N'SET UpdateStatus = 0' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                  N'OUTPUT inserted.UpdateStatus' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                  N'INTO @RI' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                  N'WHERE id = ' + QUOTENAME(Rowid,'''') + N';' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                  N'SELECT @status = CASE WHE UpdateStatus = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                  N'FROM @RI;'
    FROM dbo.logs
    WHERE id = @id;

   PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend
   EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@id int, @status tinyint OUTPUT', @id, @status OUTPUT;
END;
```

If you get any errors, use your best friend to help you. Otherwise post some sample data and expected results in your question, so that we can test (as we can't right now).

Comment: Youre a LifeSave Man Thankyou Soooooo Much It Works As I want <3

Comment: The important thing is, @MoiezHussain, is do you udnerstand it?

Comment: honestly speaking ! i didnt understand it but iam happy that it works for me and resulting output as i want XD

Comment: Taking the time to understand it is important. This explains some of the logic behind what I've done here: [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql) however, if there are parts you needs explaining please do ask. At the end of the day it's **you** who needs to be able to support the above code; not me or anyone else on Stack Overflow.